# Does the AFP Service ACL still exist in 10.9 Server.app?

Tags: time-machine, macos, server.app, afp

All I'm really trying to do is set up my wife's laptop to use my Mac Pro as a network Time Machine server. We both recently upgraded to Mavericks and I just installed Server.app.

Problem is all connection attempts from her account fail, and I can't work out why (after *lots* of time and effort diagnosing the problem).

One [ars forum post](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1147313) describes a similar problem, and one of the suggestions is that the connection is being blocked by a SACL. This theory is validated by the fact that I *can* connect with my own (admin) account.

More searching, and it seems that the suggestion is to edit the SACL using the Server Admin app. I guess this has now been rolled into Server.app?

Can someone please enlighten me, where are Service ACLs configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable individual access to services for users and groups inside of Server.app 3.0. Select the Users or Groups section from the sidebar, and then click on the user or group that you'd like to configure access for. Click on the action (gear) icon below the list of users or groups, and choose "Edit Access to Services...":

[image: Choose "Edit Access to Services"]

You'll be presented with a list of services that allow access to be enabled and disabled for this user/group. If the list is disabled, you may need to choose to "Manage Service Access":

[image: Service Access window]

The software may prompt you to confirm your choice to enable management of Service Access:

[image: Manage Access prompt]

Some information on how to [configure these checkboxes using `dseditgroup` is available](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4084). It should also be noted that [users from external directories are denied access to services by default](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5417).

If you're just trying to confirm that the user is inside of the group that's allowed to access the AFP service, you can perform this command:

```
dscl localhost read /Local/Default/Groups/com.apple.access_afp GroupMembership
```

If the command reports that the record is not found (-14136), you probably don't have an ACL applied to the AFP service.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I had found this screen, and confirmed that both file sharing and time machine services were enabled for the user. However I am unable to confirm membership with the `dscl` command, as it returns `read: Invalid Path
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14009 (eDSUnknownNodeName)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Alastair I've corrected the `dscl` command that was provided in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much - didn't help me fix my problem but it did rule out at least one possibility.

Comment: By the way, would you advise anything else to check as to why this other account cannot connect to perform a time machine backup? (checked password many times, now SACL)

Comment: @Alastair Can you provide a screenshot of what the permissions look like inside of System Preferences -> Sharing -> File Sharing? Alternately, performing the Terminal command `ls -ale /Path/To/Folder` may also provide some helpful info.